# Error System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, runtime-error

I am now suddenly getting the following message in only 1 page. What could be the issue?

I am doing a web site with MVC ASP .NET.

> System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005):
>   c: \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\fcd5a636\19fe4d1\App_Web_create.cshtml.c6727781.9mayykrj.0.cs(162):
>   error CS1528: Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in
>   declaration) at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String
>   virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String
>   controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]&
>   searchedLocations) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String
>   locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String
>   cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean
>   useCache) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindView>b__b(IViewEngine
>   e) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean
>   trackSearchedPaths) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c_*DisplayClass6.<>c*_DisplayClassb.b_*5()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c*_DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b__0(Action f)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action
>   action) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Can you be more detail with your requirement, On what code  you are getting this error? Can you put a break point in your code and confirm which line, its throwing this exception.

Comment: I already put breakpoints. None of the breakpoints are hit. This happens in Create Products Page.

Comment: can you share the Controller and View in which you are getting this exception?

Answer (score 3):

This erros means: **Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration)**

A reference to a class was formed as if an object to the class was being created. For example, there was an attempt to pass a variable to a constructor. Use the new operator to create an object of a class.

The following sample generates CS1528:

```
// CS1528.cs
using System;

public class B
{
   public B(int i)
   {
      _i = i;
   }

   public void PrintB()
   {
      Console.WriteLine(_i);
   }

   private int _i;
}

public class mine
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      B b(3);   // CS1528, reference is not an object
      // try one of the following
      // B b;
      // or
      // B bb = new B(3);
      // bb.PrintB();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.
[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbk331e6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: In the above case, a breakpoint will be hit. But its not the case here. The code was working fine. Im suspecting whether its something to do with the temporary files?

Comment: Show your Controller and View where this is being called.

Comment: This was generated from a syntax error in my View. I had accidentally typed a letter outside a <div> tag. Thanks everyone.